How to publish a KMM module to use it in another KMM project in commonMain
I'm in a KMM project, in which I have a kmm module that I want to build it and use it's artifacts in another KMM project (I want to have a kmm library). But in build/outputs de ce module, I have only a .aar artifact, which works only for Android, what should I do in this fact to build a kmm artifact ?
Actually I'm using only Windows and I don't have a mac one, is this even possible to generate a kmm artifact from this kmm module ?
I'm trying to have a kmm artifacts from a kmm module but I have only .aar that works only on Android, so when I use this .aar only androidMain recognize this library.

The build/outputs/ directory is exclusively used by the Android Gradle Plugin, so you'll only find Android-related outputs here (like aars or apks). Other Kotlin Multiplatform outputs (jars, klibs...) are in build/libs/.
To answer your other question, building Apple targets require Xcode, which is only available on macOS, thus requiring a Mac.

In build/libs I only found this : -metadata.jar, I tried to consume this artifact in my second kmm project but this is don't work. How should I consume my kmm library in the second project in commonMain.

You could publish your library to a local maven repository like Peter Tran suggested. All you would have to do is add the publish plugin to your library's build.gradle, setup basic configuration like group name and version, and run :your-library:publishToMavenLocal. You can then add the local repository to your main project's gradle config (mavenLocal()) and finally add the library as a dependency.

The question describes two KMP projects, with project A depending on project B. I believe you have to options:

If you can build project B as a source dependency then try using gradle's Composite Build feature.

Otherwise if project B can only be a binary dependency then try publishing to a local maven repository. This works for all targets for a KMP library (not just Android AAR).



My question involves two separate KMM projects, A and B. I have a module C in project A that I want to use in project B. I don’t want to move the entire module to project B, but I do want to build project A, generate a KMM artifact for module C, and move it to project B. Then, I want to consume it in the commonMain of project B (implementation(file("kmmartifact"))). Unlike Android, where an .aar file works, KMM doesn't allow using .aar as it’s Android-specific.

Mohamed Chaabouni you should be able to use option (2) "Publishing multiplatform libraries" https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-publish-lib.html . This supports all targets for the KMP lib not just Android AAR.

There are 2 ways,
Simple way:

You have 2 KMM prj: A & B

include prj B into prj A, as module

in settings.gradle.kts of prj A, include module prj B

in app build.gradle of prj A, implemenation it


Advance way:

You have 2 KMM prj: A & B

With prj B, you built: *.aar & *.xcframework

Prj A, include *.aar into /androidMain

Prj A, include *.xcframework into /iosMain


I recommend Simple way, it not took much time.
You can try with Cloud settings (maven, mvn, git ...) with above steps.
